# How to escape child element and have them in output in desire format through xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Sorry my input xml some how have been changed, Now I have edited it and below instance is the right one.

I have an XML input like:

```
<TBLROW>
   <TBLCELL COLSTART="1" COLSPAN="1" ROWSPAN="1">Personal</TBLCELL>
   <TBLCELL COLSTART="2" COLSPAN="2" ROWSPAN="1">Verbrauchsmaterialien*
   <TBLCELL COLSTART="3" COLSPAN="1" ROWSPAN="1">public
  <TBLCELL COLSTART="3" COLSPAN="1" ROWSPAN="1">private</TBLCELL>
  </TBLCELL></TBLCELL>
</TBLCELL>
```

I want output as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>Personal</td>
    <td>Verbrauchsmaterialien*</td>
    <td>public</td>
    <td>private</td>
</tr>
```

Can we do this transformation through xslt?

Comment: The answer is "yes", we can. Please don't ask people to write your code for you. At least show that you have tried to make an effort to write it yourself. Downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

The inputfile you gave has some closing tag issues. After a correction the following can be done;

```
$ cat tables.xml
<TBLROW>
        <TBLCELL COLSTART="1" COLSPAN="1" ROWSPAN="1">Personal</TBLCELL>
        <TBLCELL COLSTART="2" COLSPAN="2" ROWSPAN="1">Verbrauchsmaterialien*</TBLCELL>
        <TBLCELL COLSTART="3" COLSPAN="1" ROWSPAN="1">public</TBLCELL>
        <TBLCELL COLSTART="3" COLSPAN="1" ROWSPAN="1">private</TBLCELL>
</TBLROW>

$ cat tables.xls
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
                <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//TBLCELL">
                                <td>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

$ xsltproc tables.xls tables.xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<tr>
<td>Personal</td>
<td>Verbrauchsmaterialien*</td>
<td>public</td>
<td>private</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but input was not as before now i have added write instance of input xml

Answer (score 0):

Elegant way of matching the different elements and creating the output of them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="TBLROW">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TBLCELL">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
```